# Capturing error of entity.entityAspect.entityManager.createEntity

Tags: breeze

when I run below code -

```
this.entity.entityAspect.entityManager.createEntity('TblReceipt', {

ReceiptNo : 123
....
});
```

The code runs fine the first time and creates the new entity. Now, when the user tries to run it again its give below error -

```
   Uncaught Error: A MergeStrategy of 'Disallowed' does not allow you to attach     an entity when an entity with the same key is already attached"
```

The above error shows up in console. How I can catch this error in javascript code and show message to user?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah got it. Just wrap them in try catch block -

```
try {

}
Catch(error)
{

}
```